# Why is text column getting a float dtype error

Tags: python, pandas, types, google-colaboratory

I have a csv with titles and text for analysis. I am making a third column which combines each title and body of text so I can continue with cleaning, but I am getting this error. Neither of these columns are numeric, so I am at a loss for why this error is happening and how to fix it.

```
df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['title'] + ' ' + row['body'], axis = 1)



<ipython-input-20-326b7df1d9c7> in <lambda>(row)
----> 1 df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['title'] + ' ' + row['body'], axis = 1)
      2 print(df)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

I thought maybe it is due to encode error so I tried reading the file into colab  with this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['ASD.csv']), encoding = 'utf8')
```

that didn't work at all, but I only recently switched to using colab, so maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a small data example with which the error occurs?

Comment: The data was scrapped from reddit and includes regex issues like this: "Iâ€™m just up in my feelings right now." When I just write a sample dataset myself, the code works fine, it just isn't working with this particular dataset. (I can't share the actual dataset due to IRB restriction)

Comment: I can suggest adding `try.. except` in the function you are applying to your dataframe (instead of lambda) and printing out the row, when you catch `TypeError`. That way you will not where exactly the problem is.

Comment: [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to make sure you dont have a `nan` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. i assumed how you created you dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    "title": ["Article 1", "Article 2", "Article 3"],
    "body": ["This is the conIâ€™m of Article 1.", "This is the content of Article 2.", "This is the content of Article 3."]
}

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['title'] + ' ' + row['body'], axis = 1)

print(df)
```

It outputs before and after with new 'text' column